# NVIDIA Drivers Not Recognized 22.04 LTS (they are shown, they are not used)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

## Premis

I tried pretty much everything I could find, I will list the attempts below.

Question structured as follows: Premis, Problem, Question, Attempts.

**My PC:**

- Gigabyte X570 I AORUS PRO WIFI Mini ITX AM4
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600x (Zen3)
- Palit Dual GeForce RTX **3060Ti 8GB**
- MX500 1TB (Ubuntu)
- Sabrent Rocket 4.0 500GB (Windows)
- MX500 2TB (storage)

**Also:**

- Secure Boot is Disabled (so also CSM is disabled)

### Objective

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Installation for Machine Learning development, mainly GPU accelerated:

1. **CUDA is needed**
2. Nouveau drivers are not optimal, hence they are currently blacklisted
3. **NVIDIA drivers are needed**

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

## Problem

The driver **is** recognized as:

- It is shown in the Software & Updates as *installed*

[Software & Updates Screenshot link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNJ5s.png)

But it is clearly **not used** as I'm writing this in 1024x768 (4:3).

Taking a look at drivers/**what is recognized**:

```
teniu@AW-PC:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for teniu: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3060 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:108 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

```
teniu@AW-PC:~$ modinfo $(modprobe --resolve-alias nvidia)
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic
modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename.
```

Trying to **install drivers with autoinstall, output**:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 432, in autoinstall
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

Ignoring this means **installing the drivers specifying the version**, so with:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530-open
```

It does its thing, **then trying nvidia-smi, output**:

```
No devices were found
```

Is the kernel module loaded? Seems like it is:

```
teniu@AW-PC:~$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1441792  0
nvidia_drm             77824  1
nvidia_modeset       1404928  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia               6234112  5 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        200704  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   581632  5 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
```

Trying again to see if nvidia is seen:

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

```
teniu@AW-PC:~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3060 Ti] (rev a1)
09:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Seems like it.

## Question & Recap

```
nvidia-smi
```

Doesn't work, but the drivers are seen? I am clueless now.

The Ubuntu 22.04 LTS used for this is a fresh install.

What I think can be a major hint is this output, since NVIDIA modules are not found in the kernel modules directory.

```
teniu@AW-PC:~$ modinfo $(modprobe --resolve-alias nvidia)
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic
modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename.
```

- **What am I supposed to do now?**

## Attempts (all failed)

- Purge and reinstall (multiple)
- Changing to 515 drivers instead of 530 (twice)
- (did I install the wrong version...?)
- Disabling Secure Boot (and try again everything)
- Fresh Ubuntu install
- Test on Windows (it works there, no hardware problems)
- Headers update, 0 updates

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

- (I would like to avoid manual installation through download)
- Give up (not an option)

### Useful but unrelated information

When I built the PC I had to **update the BIOS** since the motherboard didn't offer native support for the **Zen3** architecture of the Ryzen 5 series.

I mention this only because at startup, I see the fast terminal gibberish and at the top there is written something about the AMD not being recognized. A**lthough I highly doubt it is somehow related or of importance, since it works afterwards.**

Comment: Have you tried a driver not ending in "-open"?  Sometimes that confuses some scripts checking for version numbers at the end of the driver name.

Comment: @ubfan1 I can't believe that was it, I even tried to change version but got tricked by the "-open". I will Answer my own question with this solution, I don't think it was a known problem but just in case, would you mind indicating some useful resources as to why the driver check is done through the name? It seems very unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The drivers version check is done at the end of the name, so if "-open" is at the end it might confuse some scripts, as indicated by @ubfan1.

So you can just check a **recommended** version for your specific card [here (official NVIDIA drivers)](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and look at the version.

Among the Software & Updates you can find the correct drivers version that doesn't end in "-open" and install that one.

[Screenshot of the correct version that solved my problem, yours might be different.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dVNu.png)

**Note**: it might take a while.

I might want to add the the `autoinstall` for `ubuntu-drivers` didn't work for what seems like an internal error.

I suggest to not manually (directly downloading &) install drivers as they are harder to mantain.